# unable to create dynamic events in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

i have a situation in which i m trying to create events dynamically using the plugin fullcalendar im trying to create events with the help of the ajax call and the data retrieved is in the form of json 
when i m trying to create events only event at index 0 is getting created rest of events are not created

the javascript code is as follows

```
function showData()
{ 
    var ids = showValidData(); 
    if (ids.length != 0)
    {
         $.ajax({
         url: $("#base-url").val() ,
         type: 'POST',
         data: {'ids': ids},
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (response)
         {
             var data = response.data;
             var myevents = [];
             if (response.success)
             {
                 $(data).each(function (index, value) {
                      myevents.push({
                          title: value.layoutName,
                          start: value.startDate,
                          end: value.endDate
                          });
                });
                console.log(myevents);
                $(".fc-event-container").click();
                $('#calendar-example-1').fullCalendar({
                    events: myevents,});
                return;

            }
        }   
       });
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set events when initializing FullCalendar - define the url of the script that returns a json of events from your database (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/). If you want to dynamically refresh the calendar , you can add a setInterval ontop:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 setInterval(function(){$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')}, 30000);


$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
 ...
 events: {
    url: 'script.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        data1: x,
        data2: y
    },
    success : function(response){
    // do something
    },
 }
});
});
```

Comment: instead of passing url of json data in the events i m passing the json data itself to the events in full calendar still the events are not getting created any suggestion would be of great help

Comment: if you could create a jsfiddle showcasing the problem, it would help

Comment: actually the above problem was solved with the help of renderevents function of fullcalendar